# jQuery UI carousel - rcarousel plugin rcarousel directions

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I'm using jQuery UI carousel - rcarousel plugin (http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/) and i would like to change the direction of this plugin. For example, when the user click on right arrow i would like that carousel were to right direction. Below is the Jquery code that i'm using:

```
jQuery(function($) {$( "#carousel").rcarousel ({visible: 5, margin: 10, step: 5, });$( "#ui-carousel-prev" ).add( "#ui-carousel-next").hover(function() {$( this ).css( "opacity", 0.7 );},function() {$( this ).css( "opacity", 1.0 );});});
```

How do i do this? Thanks.

Comment: That's going to run counter to expected standard behavior and confuse a lot of folks. Are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in the Public API that you can use on your buttons: http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/#api

Something like this would work:

```
$('#rightBtn').click(function() {
  $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( "prev" );
}

$('#leftBtn').click(function() {
  $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( "next" );
}
```

This essentially reverses the default behavior. I reiterate what I said in my comment, though. This will mostly serve to confuse.

As you're new to SO I'll remind you to accept an answer by clicking its checkmark and/or upvote any that you find helpful.

Comment: Hi isherwood, thanks for the answer. In this case "#rightBtn" means "ui-carousel-next"? Thanks again.

Comment: See this example: http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/examples/margin.html . When you click on Right button the carousel move to left. I would like to change this.

Comment: It may. Change the selector to whatever you're using. You haven't provided us any code, so I can't say.

Comment: I'm using this code on the main page:

----
<div id="content">      
<div id="container">

<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-next"></a>
<a href="#" id="ui-carousel-prev"></a>

<div id="carousel">

<img src="../images/01.jpg" />
<img src="../images/01.jpg" />
<img src="../images/01.jpg" />
<img src="../images/01.jpg" />

</div>

</div>

</div>

----